# Unable to install Oracle XE 18c on Centos 8

Tags: installation, centos, oracle-18c

I am trying to install Oracle 18 on Centos 8 64 Bit.

I have been able to install the prerequiste component, that in itself requires pre-requisites, but the Oracle install itself fails.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

My system is as follows.

```
[root@localhost ~]# uname -a

Linux localhost.localdomain 4.18.0-80.11.2.el8_0.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 24 11:32:19 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have run the following without incident.

```
    [root@localhost ~]# yum -y localinstall compat-libcap1-1.10-7.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

```
    [root@localhost ~]# yum -y localinstall compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

```
    [root@localhost ~]# yum -y localinstall oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

When I try and install Oracle it fails.

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum -y localinstall oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:01 ago on Sun 24 Nov 2019 18:06:23 AEDT.
Dependencies resolved.
=============================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                             Arch                                Version                             Repository                                 Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 oracle-database-xe-18c                              x86_64                              1.0-1                               @commandline                              2.4 G

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 2.4 G
Installed size: 5.2 G
Downloading Packages:
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                     1/1
  Running scriptlet: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64                                                                                                                 1/1
  Installing       : oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64                                                                                                                 1/1
  Running scriptlet: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64                                                                                                                 1/1
Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/oui/lib/linux64/liboraInstaller.so: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory occurred..
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/oui/lib/linux64/liboraInstaller.so: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.loadNativeLib(OiipuUnixOps.java:388)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.<clinit>(OiipuUnixOps.java:130)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgEnvironment.getEnv(OiipgEnvironment.java:201)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniPair.instantiateEnvVars(OiixIniPair.java:299)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniPair.updateValue(OiixIniPair.java:230)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniPair.<init>(OiixIniPair.java:148)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniFile.readFile(OiixIniFile.java:809)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniFile.readIniFile(OiixIniFile.java:978)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniFile.getProfileString(OiixIniFile.java:385)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixOraparam.getOraparamProfileString(OiixOraparam.java:339)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixOraparam.getOraparamProfileString(OiixOraparam.java:297)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixOraparam.usePrereqChecker(OiixOraparam.java:417)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicSessionContext.setVariables(OiicSessionContext.java:1325)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.execute(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:766)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.main_helper(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:685)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicDetachHome.main(OiicDetachHome.java:420)
'DetachHome' failed.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.main_helper(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:701)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicDetachHome.main(OiicDetachHome.java:420)
Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/oui/lib/linux64/liboraInstaller.so: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory occurred..
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/oui/lib/linux64/liboraInstaller.so: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.loadNativeLib(OiipuUnixOps.java:388)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.<clinit>(OiipuUnixOps.java:130)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgEnvironment.getEnv(OiipgEnvironment.java:201)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniPair.instantiateEnvVars(OiixIniPair.java:299)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniPair.updateValue(OiixIniPair.java:230)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniPair.<init>(OiixIniPair.java:148)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniFile.readFile(OiixIniFile.java:809)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniFile.readIniFile(OiixIniFile.java:978)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixIniFile.getProfileString(OiixIniFile.java:385)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixOraparam.getOraparamProfileString(OiixOraparam.java:339)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixOraparam.getOraparamProfileString(OiixOraparam.java:297)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixOraparam.usePrereqChecker(OiixOraparam.java:417)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicSessionContext.setVariables(OiicSessionContext.java:1325)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.execute(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:766)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.main_helper(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:685)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicAttachHome.main(OiicAttachHome.java:696)
'AttachHome' failed.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.main_helper(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:701)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicAttachHome.main(OiicAttachHome.java:696)
[SEVERE] An error occurred while registering the Oracle home. Verify logs in /var/log/oracle-database-xe-18c/results/oraInstall.log and /opt/oracle/oraInventory for more details and try again.
warning: %post(oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1

Error in POSTIN scriptlet in rpm package oracle-database-xe-18c
  Verifying        : oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64                                                                                                                 1/1

Installed:
  oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64

Complete!
```

Comment: Total guess - have you tried to install libnsl-devel?

Answer (score 2):

The answer wasn't obvious.  If you follow the documentation and various posts for installing Oracle XE 18c there appears to be some missing steps if you only use yum to do the installation.

Firstly if you run the install for the prerequisites file using yum you get a response back saying there are two missing dependant files.

If you then run the same using rpm -ivh the result is different.  See below.

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum -y localinstall oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                                                11 kB/s | 4.5 kB     00:00    
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)                                                                  6.8 kB/s | 4.1 kB     00:00    
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides compat-libcap1 needed by oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides compat-libstdc++-33 needed by oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
[root@localhost ~]#
```

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -ivh oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

```
warning: oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    compat-libcap1 is needed by oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
    compat-libstdc++-33 is needed by oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
    ksh is needed by oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
    libaio-devel is needed by oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
    libstdc++-devel is needed by oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
    sysstat is needed by oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
    xorg-x11-utils is needed by oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
[root@localhost ~]#
```

I also realised that I hadn't at that stage installed java.  However just installing this didn't help either.

The resolution for me was to install the dependancies highlighted by rpm -ivh, then install java and then install libnsl, one more rpm that java was complaining about.

My solution is as follows.

```
yum install -y gcc-c++ make
yum install -y ksh
yum install -y sysstat
yum install -y xorg-x11-utils
yum install -y libnsl
yum install java-11-openjdk-devel
rpm -ivh libaio-devel-0.3.110-12.el8.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh compat-libcap1-1.10-7.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Then install the Oracle files.

```
rpm -ivh oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
rpm -ivh oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

I don't know if this is the most optimal way of going about the Oracle install but it has worked for me now on both a RHEL and Centos system.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement this excellent answer and also because CentOS is no more, I found the required packages on Oracles YUM repo:

https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/0/base/x86_64/index.html

Hopefully this helps anyone scrounging for a reliable repo to pull packages.

Comment: The question is not about where to find the packages though, is it?